# Php fopen or fwrite creates text with unicode

Tags: php, character-encoding, fwrite

I'm trying to write a file with fopen and fwrite. I have an array that displays fine when printing it.

For instance i can see `"Délai de livraison"` being printed out.

After creating a file, it is displayed as: `"D\u00e9lai de livraison"`.
And "\u00e9" is unicode if I understand right.

I have tried adding a "BOM" and writing it to the beginning of the file, but there is no change.

```
//Write $newarray to a file   

$filename = 'translations_fr.json';

 //create json file
 $file = base_path('/imports/') . $filename;
 $fp = fopen($file, 'w');

 //BOM 
  fwrite($fp, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");

fwrite($fp, json_encode($newarray));
fclose($fp);
```

My IDE is Netbeans and it is configured with UTF-8 as default.
I tried utf8_encode(), but no luck.
What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a BOM or `fwrite()` issue. `json_encode()` will turns all multibyte characters into unicode format, by default.

But you could use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option :

```
echo json_encode(['test'=>'délai']);
echo json_encode(['test'=>'délai'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Outputs :

```
{"test":"d\u00e9lai"}
{"test":"délai"}
```

From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php):

> Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.